# User Permissions Reverting After Save

Tags: bash, permissions, chmod

I am using Redhat 6.9. I don't have root permissions.

I have created a bash script called "script" (no extension).

When I use `chmod +x script` to make it executable, I can run the script successfully. However, if I change the script and save it, the script seems to lose its executable status. I have confirmed this by typing `ls -l` and seeing:

`-rw-rwxr-- ... script`

Typing `chmod +x script` then `ls -l` yields

`-rwxrwxr-- ... script`

I can execute the script with `./script` successfully at this point multiple times.

However, after modifying and saving the script, `ls -l` yields:

`-rw-rwxr-- ... script`

The --x---- bit is cleared for some reason. If I try to execute now, I get the error:

`bash: ./script Permission denied`

I know others have recommended sudo, but that option is not available to me. Is there any other way to force the script to forever be executable? And not have to use `chmod +x` after every save?

Comment: How are you editing the script?  Is it possible that instead of modifying the existing file you are overwriting it with a new file of the same name?

Comment: I'm editing it in notepad++. Does notepad++ overwrite instead of modify? Is there a way to force it to only modify instead of overwrite?

Comment: What does running the command `umask` show? The umask generally controls what permissions newly-created files receive.

Comment: `umask` shows 0007

Comment: Maybe this question can provide some insight: https://superuser.com/questions/541270/strange-permission-changes-when-saving-file-on-a-samba-partition-from-a-windows

Comment: I use notepad++ from a windows vm for my script editing and have never encountered this issue, however I share the files from my mac to the windows VM and not the other way around so maybe that's why.